# MVC Partial Control: "cannot find an IViewDataContainer object. The ViewUserControl must be inside a ViewPage, a ViewMasterPage"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to implement SSRS viewer in MVC.  After alot of pain and suffering I've got this basically working via a custom control.

The report renders fine, but I'm trying to pass in the Model to the control like this:

```
@Html.Partial("VendorReport", Model)
```

To call this ascx control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VendorReport.ascx.cs" Inherits="ExtendedServicesReportingPortal.Views.Reports.VendorReport" %>
```

```
<uc1:RazorReportViewer ID="VendorReportViewer" runat="server" ...Omitted Custom Properties...  />
```

But I'm getting this error if I try and access the Model:

```
The ViewUserControl '~/Views/Reports/RazorReportViewer.ascx' cannot find an IViewDataContainer object. The ViewUserControl must be inside a ViewPage, a ViewMasterPage
```

Here's the relevant controller controller method:

```
public ActionResult TransactionCountsAndInvoiceAmounts(TransactionCountsAndInvoiceAmountsModel model)
    {
        if(model == null) model = new TransactionCountsAndInvoiceAmountsModel();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Very new to MVC, what am I missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that where you are using a User Control the `ViewPage.Model` property will be null since the control does not have access to/use of ViewData. You will likely need to pass the model into the user control.

There are some examples [here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/05/12/38297/) and also [here](http://malvinly.com/2011/02/28/using-web-forms-user-controls-in-an-asp-net-mvc-project/) that show reusing Web Form user controls in MVC views including passing in the model.